# How to return entire uint storage array in function? (solidity ^v0.5.12) Auto-generated function returns only first element

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
contract sample {
 mapping(address => uint256[12]) fruits;
 function getfruit(address addr) public view returns (uint256[] storage fr) { //line 3
  return (fruits[addr]);
 }
}
```

Look at the above code. Here firstly since fruits is public, getfruit() should not be even required. But the auto-generated fruits() only returns index 0 (only the first element) but I want all.
Now as far as function is concerned, it gives error when I use 'storage' in line 3. Now if I make it memory , I tried the following code but still throws error saying 'TypeError: Type uint256[12] is not implicitly convertible to uint256[] memory' (which sounds reasonable, but then how do I get the array)?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
contract sample {
 mapping(address => uint256[12]) fruits;
 function getfruit(address addr) public view returns (uint256[] storage fr) { //line 3
  uint256[] memory veggies = new uint256[] (12);
  veggies = fruits[addr];
  return (veggies);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
uint256[] storage fr
```

To this:

```
uint256[12] memory
```

Comment: Still returns just the first element.

Comment: @learningOneErrorAtATime: What do you mean "still"? In your question you've described a compilation error. How could there be "still" in here if you couldn't even compile the contract and call this function beforehand???

Comment: My bad. Tried several ways. So I was talking for the auto-generated function returning only first element. Now if we just write, 
function getfruit(address addr) public view returns (uint256[12] memory fr) { return (fruits[addr])} 
still returns first element.

Comment: @learningOneErrorAtATime: The auto-generated function indeed returns only the first element. But you've posted your own (manually-generated) function, which I've instructed you how to fix. How exactly were you thinking to apply my suggestion on the auto-generated function???

Comment: Please show how you're calling function `getfruit`, and what brings you to the conclusion that it only returns 1 element of the array.

Comment: Running everything on remix

Comment: @learningOneErrorAtATime: Are you calling function `fruits` or function `getfruit`?

Comment: Called both. Both behave the same way. By the way I can store elements directly at specific index in this size 12 array right? And by default the value would be zero for rest of the indices?

Comment: You know I have tried the same thing, just with address instead pointing to a struct which in itself contains array and then the return function works just the way expected (as in returning all array elements). I seriously can't figure out why mapping directly to an array is behaving this way in the function.

Comment: @learningOneErrorAtATime: Yes for the question above. And I believe that function `fruits` actually takes two arguments as input - an `address` (for the mapping itself) and a `uint` (for the index within the mapped array).

Comment: @learningOneErrorAtATime: And please see my update to the answer. You should omit the `fr` in the return-value name. Otherwise the function just instantiates an (empty) array named `fr` and returns it. I think (but omit it anyway).

Comment: Oh good grace! Where were you all this while... removing fr worked!! Thanks!

Comment: @learningOneErrorAtATime: Feel free to accept the answer then.